How to optimize server side rendering in next.js 14 when using react hooks (e.g. MUI useTheme)
To toggle between dark and light mode I use Material UIs 'useTheme' hook and a ThemeProvider that wraps my application.
I use the theme in pretty much all of my layout components. That means that I would have to make them all a server side component with the 'use client' directive.
Now I try to - at least - render all text content on the server to make it easier for search engines to better crawl and index the content of the page.
I'm new to next.js and need to better understand SSR and CSR so my question is: Is there any value in this? Or am I just making it too complicated?
See for example this description card. Does it make any sense to do it like this or should I just make the whole card a client side component and put the description right into the card component?
// my server side card component wrapper
import Description from './Description';
import DescCard from './DescCard';

export default function MyServerCardWrapper(){

    return(
        <DescCard>
            <Description/>
        </DescCard>
    )
}

// server side rendered description
export default function Description () {
    return(
        <>
            {"Description rendered on the server side in order for search engines to better crawl and index the content of the page"}
        </>
    )
}

// client side card component that uses useTheme
'use client'

import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Card, CardContent } from '@mui/material';
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";


export default function DescCard({children}){

    const theme = useTheme();

    return(
        <Card style={{backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper}} elevation={0} 
                sx={{
                    borderColor: theme.palette.primary.light
                }}
        >
            <CardContent>
                <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16 }}  gutterBottom>
                    {children}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    )
}

